# Finding the difference between arrays and update

Tags: javascript

I am wondering, what is the most efficient way to compare two arrays in a way that:

1. it finds the missing objects from array A compared to array B, and adds them to object A;
2. if object from A is different from object B, it updates the properties (objects identified by property 'id')

Any ideas?

Comment: i am a huge fan of indicating all elements of one array in a hash table and do the wanted parts with the second iteration over the other array.

Comment: You can't really have a 'most efficient' way. Also, you're essentially just copying array B into array A, so it would be best to say it that way.

Comment: What current method are you using and what issues are you having with it?

Comment: If you just want Array B to be similar to Array A --> copy it

Comment: implement both and mesure running time for each method to compare

Answer (score 0):

Usually the most efficient way is the native way, so something like this should perform pretty well:

```js
console.clear();

var one = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var two = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g'];

function insertMissing(insertTo, insertFrom) {
 insertFrom.filter(function (from) {
  return insertTo.some(function (too) {
   return too === from
  }) == false;
 }).forEach(function (el) {
  insertTo.push(el);
 })
}
insertMissing(two, one);

console.log(one, two);
```

I'll need to know the exact object markup to know what to match against, but this demonstrates the basics.

Below is a snippet demonstrating it with objects:

```js
console.clear();

var one = [{
  'id' : 'a'
 }, {
  'id' : 'b'
 }, {
  'id' : 'c'
 }, {
  'id' : 'd'
 }, {
  'id' : 'e'
 }, {
  'id' : 'f'
 }, {
  'id' : 'g'
 }
];
var two = [{
  'id' : 'a'
 }, {
  'id' : 'b'
 }, {
  'id' : 'c'
 }, {
  'id' : 'e'
 }, {
  'id' : 'g'
 }
];

function insertMissing(insertTo, insertFrom) {
 insertFrom.filter(function (from) {
  return insertTo.some(function (too) {
   return too.id === from.id
  }) == false;
 }).forEach(function (el) {
  insertTo.push(el);
 })
}
insertMissing(two, one);

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
```

And finally, a version that overwrites the properties of the objects:

```js
console.clear();

var one=[{'id':'a','value':1},{'id':'b','value':1},{'id':'c','value':1},{'id':'d','value':1},{'id':'e','value':3},{'id':'f','value':1},{'id':'g','value':1}];
var two=[{'id':'a','value':1},{'id':'b','value':1},{'id':'c','value':1},{'id':'e','value':1},{'id':'g','value':1}];

function insertMissing(insertTo, insertFrom) {
 //Validate existing elements
 insertTo.forEach(function (too) {
  var from;
  insertFrom.forEach(function (f, index) {
   if (f.id == too.id && typeof from == 'undefined') {
    from = index;
   }
  });
  if (typeof from == "number") {
   for (var i in insertFrom[from]) {
    if (insertFrom[from].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
     if (insertFrom[from][i] !== too[i]) {
      too[i] = insertFrom[from][i];
     }
    }
   }
  }
 });
 //Insert missing elements
 insertFrom.filter(function (from) {
  return insertTo.some(function (too) {
   return too.id === from.id
  }) == false;
 }).forEach(function (el) {
  insertTo.push(el);
 })
}
insertMissing(two, one);

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the OP has asked for the arrays to be populated by objects, which will be identified by an 'id' property.

Comment: @Tobsta I know. That was why i made the comment about markup. I have edited my answer to show how it would work with an `id` parameter.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that, but all you really need to know, or guess, is that the objects follow a basic `{id:x, ...other properties...}` format.